# JavaFX controller isnt getting content

Tags: java, javafx

Im new to using controllers in JavaFX and im having trouble. My first scene loads fine but when I click the button to move to the second scene nothing comes up just a blank box. Any clues on how to load my 2nd scene?

Here is my starter scene:

```
public class ControllerConnect implements Controller{
    private final FlowPane root;
    public ControllerConnect() {
        //Connection page objects
        TextField username = new TextField();
        TextField password = new TextField();
        username.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        password.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Button connect = new Button("Connect");
        connect.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world";
                String name = username.getText();
                String pass = password.getText();

                try {
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, name, pass);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                ControllerCity controller2 = new ControllerCity();
                connect.getScene().setRoot(controller2.getContent());


            }
        });
        root = new FlowPane(connect);
        Label user = new Label("Username:");
        Label pass = new Label("Password:");
        user.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pass.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        username.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        password.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        connect.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox connectionBox = new VBox(10, user, username, pass, password, connect);
        connectionBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(connectionBox);
        root.setMinSize(640, 480);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


    }
    @Override
    public Parent getContent() {
        return root;
    }
}
```

Here is my 2nd scene only half finished but the buttons should show:

```
public class ControllerCity implements Controller {
    private final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    public ControllerCity() {
        //Layout for city pane
        //HBox for buttons

        Button populate = new Button("Populate/Update");
        Button delete = new Button("Delete");
        Button create = new Button("Create");
        HBox cityButtons = new HBox(populate, delete, create);
        root.setBottom(cityButtons);
        //HBox for TableView
        HBox cityTable = new HBox();
        root.setCenter(cityTable);
        root.setMinSize(1024, 768);

    }
    @Override
    public Parent getContent() {
        return root;
    }
}
```

Application class:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ControllerConnect controllerconnect = new ControllerConnect();
    Scene scene = new Scene(
            controllerconnect.getContent()
    );

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: @Yahya Why not?

Comment: I removed the finals but that didnt solve the problem.

Comment: These look more like views than controllers. Can you show the application class - I assume you are just creating a scene, settings its root to be `new ControllerConnect().getContent()`, etc. There are no exceptions, presumably?

Comment: added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons are present: you just can't see them.

The issue is that your first "controller" (which is surely a view, not a controller) sets a minimum size of `640 x 480` pixels. The scene will size to the preferred size of the root, which in this case will be `640 x 480` (because the controls in the first scene do not need more space than that).

Your second scene sets a minimum size of `1024 x 768`. So the second view is now bigger than the stage containing it, and the buttons are out of view.

If you expand the window after pressing the "Connect" button, you will see the buttons.

If you replace

```
ControllerCity controller2 = new ControllerCity();
connect.getScene().setRoot(controller2.getContent());
```

in the button's event handler with

```
ControllerCity controller2 = new ControllerCity();
Scene scene = connect.getScene();
scene.setRoot(controller2.getContent());
scene.getWindow().sizeToScene();
```

then the window will resize so you can see the buttons.